# Videos recorded with JavaScript MediaRecorder have no duration (not just from Chrome)

Tags: javascript, video, blob, video-capture, mediastream

Before you say "this is just a Chrome bug" like every similar question from years ago was answered, I tried it on Firefox and the same thing happened.
I wrote a little program to save pictures and videos because my phone camera app is broken and I don't have the space to download a new one. The pictures work fine, but when I try to save a video it has no duration. This stops it from playing on my phone and my video editing software, and when I play it on my computer it has no information on the time besides how much has elapsed (so it'll say, for example, 7 seconds, but still have the dot at the beginning of the progress bar on an 8 second video).
Here's the main code for the video recording:

```js
async function getCam(facingMode='user') {
  media = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {facingMode}, audio: true})
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(media);
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
    vidChunks.push(e.data)
  }
  mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
    const vid = new Blob(vidChunks, {type: 'video/mp4'})
    vidChunks = [];
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(vid);
    a.download = `${Date.now()}vid.mp4`
    a.click();
  }
  video.srcObject = media;
  video.play();
  facing = facingMode;
}
```

The full code can be found [here](https://replit.com/@morganmakes/camera#script.js).
Am I missing something? Or is this now a problem with all browsers? I tried Brave (Chromium) desktop and mobile, Edge (also Chromium now afaik), and Firefox (not Chromium, so this is not just a problem with Chrome!!!)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? What did you do in the end?

Comment: @ShahriarDhruvo no, I ended up giving up :/

Comment: I was developing in nextjs. I fixed this issue by using this package -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-webm-duration

Comment: @ShahriarDhruvo I wasn't using any framework but thx, I might try again using nextjs